# Istio VirtualService possible to require specific headers for certain routes (and reject otherwise)

Tags: http, kubernetes, istio

I am using Istio VirtualService and am wondering if it's possible to use the header rules to deny requests on specific routes if a header is missing.

per the docs it looks like we can only add or remove headers at virtualservice level? Is that correct?

Or in what way can I blanket deny requests to specific URI paths in the virtualservice without a specific header?

Comment: take a look at https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPMatchRequest

Answer (score 2):

Virtual service focuses only on [rewriting and routing](https://istio.io/v1.1/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/control-headers/) including headers and it doesnt support denying traffic without the header. However Upon checking [EnvoyFilter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/) it can manipulate deny requests based on header condition.

Sharing also this [link](https://discuss.istio.io/t/add-headers-using-virtual-service/2786) where one of the comments uses EnvoyFilter to manipulate header rules. Please check the sample yaml below if this fits your concern.

```
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: any-name
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: your-app
  filters:
    - listenerMatch:
        listenerType: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        listenerProtocol: HTTP
      filterName: envoy.lua
      filterType: HTTP
      filterConfig:
        inlineCode: |
          function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
            local header_value = request_handle:headers():get("Your-Header-Name")
            if header_value == nil then
              request_handle:respond({[":status"] = "403"}, "Header is missing")
            end
          end
```